# Quill.js Blots/embed element's class filtered away on initialisation even though it's registered

Tags: javascript, jquery, quill

I have the following code:

```
const Embed = Quill.import('blots/embed');
class PlaceholderLabel extends Embed {
  static create(value) {
    const node = super.create(value);
    node.innerText = value;
    node.contentEditable = 'false';
    this._addRemovalButton(node);
    return node;
  }
  static value(node) {
    return node.childNodes[0].textContent;
  }
  static _addRemovalButton(node) {
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    $(button).prop({
      class: 'bi-x btn btn-sm p-0 m-0'
    });
    button.onclick = () => node.remove();
    node.appendChild(button);
  }
}
PlaceholderLabel.blotName = 'placeholderlabeldynamic';
PlaceholderLabel.className = 'placeholderlabeldynamic';
PlaceholderLabel.tagName = 'span';
Quill.register('formats/placeholderlabeldynamic', PlaceholderLabel, true);
quillInstance = new Quill($(quillInstanceEl)[0], {
  theme: 'snow',
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      [{ 'list': 'ordered'}],
      [{ 'indent': '-1'}, { 'indent': '+1' }]
    ],
    clipboard: {
      matchVisual: false
    }
  },
  formats: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'list', 'indent', 'placeholderlabeldynamic']
});
```

When I call `quillInstance.insertEmbed(index, 'placeholderlabeldynamic', placeholderVal, Quill.sources.USER);`, the blot is added and works as imagined, with an uneditable label that has a remove button. The issue is as follows:

1. Button is pressed, that executes `quillInstance.insertEmbed(index, 'placeholderlabeldynamic', placeholderVal, Quill.sources.USER);`, the caller mentioned above.
2. Blot is added to Quill as expected.
3. Contents of Quill is sent via Ajax to backend php that stores the data, and on reload said data is inserted in Quill again.
4. Quill reads the data, but strips the class `placeholderlabeldynamic`, thus making it impossible to continue where you left off with Quill when revisiting the page.

Any help is much appreciated!

There is a comment here: ([Thread and comment highlighted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601992/how-to-add-a-non-editable-tag-to-content-in-quill-editor#comment133908856_55616254)), where a user has the same issue. Perhaps the post and its comments can be of help...
I have been stuck on this issue for days, and am hoping one of you can shed some light on the cause.